# Itô isometry respects these inner products

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I konw the Itô isometry states

\begin{equation} 
\mathbb{E} \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} \alpha_{s}
  dB_{s} \right)^{2} = \mathbb{E} \int_{0}^{\infty} \alpha_{s}^{2}
  ds\end{equation}

Can I obtain the following result:

\begin{equation} \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{T} \int_{0}^{t} f(s)dB_{s}g(t)dB_{t}\right]=\int_{0}^{T} \int_{0}^{t}f(s)g(t)dsdt\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Recall the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity), from which it follows that if $T\colon \mathcal{H_1}\to\mathcal{H_2}$ is any isometry between Hilbert spaces then necessarily $\langle Tf,Tg\rangle = \langle f,g\rangle$. Applying this to the Itô isometry, we obtain that
$$
\mathbb E\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \alpha_s\ dB_s\ \beta_t\ dB_t=\mathbb E\int_0^{\infty}\alpha_s\beta_s\ ds.
$$

Finally, choose $\alpha_s=1_{s<t}f(s)$ and $\beta_t=1_{t<T}g(t)$ to conclude.

Comment: So, in the case of $t<T$, is the following result is correct?   \begin{equation} \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{T} \int_{0}^{t} f(s)dB_{s}g(t)dB_{t}\right]=\mathbb{E}\int_{0}^{t}f(s)g(s)ds\end{equation}

Comment: That can't be right, the right side is a function of $t$ and the left side isn't.

Comment: So, what the result of  \begin{equation} \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{T} \int_{0}^{t} f(s)dB_{s}g(t)dB_{t}\right]=\mathbb{E}\int_{0}^{t}f(s)g(s)ds\end{equation}   if $t<T$.  Thanks.  

 In my opinion      
 \begin{equation} \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{T} \int_{0}^{t} f(s)dB_{s}g(t)dB_{t}\right]=  \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{t} f(s)dB_{s}g(t)dB_{t}+\int_{t}^{T} \int_{0}^{t} f(s)dB_{s}g(t)dB_{t}\right] \\
 =  \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{t} f(s)dB_{s}g(t)dB_{t}\right] 
\end{equation} 
Is this right?

Comment: You're integrating out the $t$ dependence in the outer integral, it makes no sense for it to then appear as a bound. I think you should review double integrals, as that seems to be where the confusion lies, rather than in the more elaborate notion of stochastic calculus.

Comment: I really can not follow your answer $\mathbb E\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \alpha_s\ dB_s\ \beta_t\ dB_t=\mathbb E\int_0^{\infty}\alpha_s\beta_s\ ds.$

Comment: You need to understand the Itô isometry for this to make sense. This is an isometry between certain Hilbert spaces of functions. I would recommend reviewing the concept of a Hilbert space, convincing yourself why the two function spaces appearing in the Itô isometry are Hilbert spaces, and thinking about what the inner product means in each of them. Then this answer will make sense.